# Historical data scrapping / collection for Ethereum

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain

I'm working on my thesis about Ethereum and I want to extract some historical data on a daily basis from 2016 to now (on an hourly basis could be perfect but I can do with daily).

The data I need are :

- Daily transaction on the Ethereum blockchain
- Daily market capitalization (or supply because I already have the price)
- Daily Active addresses (if possible)

Pleaseeee help me.

I tried with different APIs, like Coingecko, Coinmaketcap, and Etherscan, but only on Python as I'm familiar with it and I'm using it for my project.

Everey APIs I've tried are limited in requests or in historical data, and it's verey expensive just for 1-3 data points to take a subscription..